# Solution for $x=e^x$ in terms of elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis

While solving a problem I've come across an expression which essence is

$$x=e^x$$

It does contain more terms, but I couldn't even figure out an explicit expression for $x$ in terms of elementary functions, much less for the one that I actually came across, which is of the form

$$x=\alpha+\beta e^{\gamma x}$$

Is it possible to express the solution of this equation for $x$ in terms of elementary functions? Any ideas?

Comment: Lambert W-Function - no elementary functions. You can use numerical methods.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "elementary functions". If you allow Lambert's W function, this is possible. If you restrict yourself to a tigher range of allowed functions, like only exponentials and logarithms, then the answer is conjecturally "there is no elementary expression", which AFAIK follows from Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: I see, it seems indeed this function does not qualify for what I was looking for, so I guess this closes the discussion. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Of most use, try [the general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1)

Comment: Oh, thanks @SimpleArt, I guess I'll have to settle with expressing it like this.

Comment: @Dr.MV Pft, editting your post and such.  Humph...

Answer (score 1):

If the expression $x=e^x$ has a solution, it is simply a number $x_0$, not a function.

Note that $x=e^x \implies (-x)e^{(-x)}=-1$.  The Lambert W function, $W(z)$, is defined as

$$z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$$

Therefore, $x=e^x$ is equivalent to $x=-W(-1)$.

Note that inasmuch as $e^x\ge x$ for all $x$, the solution $x=-W(-1)$ is not a purely real number.

Comment: How do you make the conclusion "The solution is not possible in terms of elementary functions"?

Comment: @Wojowu First sentence, last paragraph of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) before the contents box.

Comment: @Wojowu Appeal to the definition.  Note that $-1=W(-1)e^{W(-1)}$ by definition.  Then, note that we have $-x=W(-1)$.

Comment: @SimpleArt That a function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions doesn't imply its values cannot be expressed so.

Comment: @Dr.MV I see why you have $x=-W(-1)$. But how do you deduce it is not expressible in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: @Wojowu $W(-1) \approx 0.31813 -i 1.33723$

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for a numerical approximation, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Wojowu At the least, it is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values)

Comment: @Wojowu The solution is a complex number so it is possible to write it in terms of the value of an elementary function.  For example, let $f(z)=-W(-1)z$.  Then, $f(1)$ is the solution.  So, I've edited and removed the claim.

Comment: If you take a quick look at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=W(-1)), it doesn't seem as though the solution is elementary in the sense you are probably asking.

Comment: @SimpleArt The solution is simply a number, not a function.  So to discuss solutions in terms of elementary functions is subject to question.

Comment: @Dr.MV This is of course correct, but this problem is much more interesting if you ask about [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Although I do not claim I think it is expressible in such form (and conjecturally it isn't), just because we know something about $W$ function itself we can't infer much about its specific values.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, it solves my doubt. I apologize for being a bit vague in the description as I'm noticing now the simplification I made allowed room for ambiguity, because in fact, the expression I come across does involve variables instead of numbers, and the $x$ I'm looking for is a function of such variables. In any case, the answer to my question is very much negative.

Comment: @Wojowu It is possible, that $W(-1)$ can be expressed without self reference using a finite number of "elementary" operations.  I'm not sure, but I believe we are in violent agreement on this one. ;-))  -Mark