# Transcendental Equation.

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-numbers, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I was able to solve $ \ln x = - x $ using Lambert's function.

I was wondering how does one solve $ \ln x = x$

Does the solution even exist for this equation?

Comment: There is no real solution (plotting the graphs is pretty convincing, but one can also prove quite easily that $\log{x} \leq x-1$ with equality precisely when $x=1$).

Comment: Taking $e\widehat~$ to both sides, you end up [solving $x=e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2018984).